# Converting Date to String in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I want to convert the date format to string, but the string output is not coming

```
  DateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy ");
  String currDateString = String.valueOf(currentDate);
  System.out.println(currDateString);
```

Comment: The DateFormat is stateless (unlike, say, the Calendar)

Comment: @MauricePerry : stateless? I don;t think so, there is lot of state in SimpleDateFormat (that's why it is not thread-safe)

Comment: @rkosegi SimpleDateFormat is a poor implementation of DateFormat.

Comment: @MauricePerry : yes, so why you said that abstract class (DateFormat) is stateless without knowing behavior of actual implementation? That is like saying that some interface is stateless ...

Comment: @rkosegi alright, let's instead say that it SHOULD be stateless

Comment: @MauricePerry It is impossible to implement the abstract class `DateFormat` in a stateless way because there are abstract setters with return type void (if you want any sensible implementation beyond no-op).

Comment: @MenoHochschild that's not the point

Comment: @MauricePerry That is the point because finally no concrete class which is really used is abstract. `DateFormat` itself is just an abstract facade. And you will always have a concrete implementation at runtime i.e. a concrete subclass which will be stateful (and I explained in my previous comment why such a subclass cannot be stateless).

Comment: @MenoHochschild OK, stateless is not the right word. What I meant is that it has no current date (unlike, say, the Calendar).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To format current date you need to create a instance of `Date` which represents current date and then format it using `SimpleDateFormat` to string.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
String currDateString = dateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(currDateString);
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: 24 01 2017    i need to convert it to 24th January 2017 ?

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy")` is the input format `new SimpleDateFomat('dd MMMM yyyy')` is output. You should refer to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)